# c++ File Reader Program

Tags: c++

Any help is appreciated. I'm writing a program that counts the different types of characters that are present in a given plain text file. It's suppose to count exclude all whitespaces, count all the letters, from those letters it will count the vowels, count all the numbers, and count the other types of characters. The text file reads: "Assignment 5 is interesting!" exactly with all spacing included and accurate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    ofstream outputFile;
    string userInput;
    int countLength, countSpace, totalVowels, totalNumbers, totalOther;
    double alphaPercent, vowelPercent, numPercent, otherPercent;
    int totalLetters[26] = {0};
    char getChar;

    totalVowels = 0;
    totalNumbers = 0;
    totalOther = 0;

    cout << "Enter the file name: " << endl;
    getline(cin, userInput);

    if (userInput == "as.5.txt")
    {
        inputFile.open("as.5.txt");

        if (inputFile.is_open())
        {
            while (getline(inputFile,userInput))
            {
                countLength+= userInput.length();
                if (userInput == " ")
                {
                    countSpace ++;
                    countLength = countLength - countSpace;

                    for (unsigned n = 0; n < userInput.length(); ++n)
                    {
                        getChar = char (userInput[n]); //reads the letters in the file

                        if (getChar == 'a'|| getChar == 'e'|| getChar == 'i' || getChar == 'o'|| getChar == 'u' || getChar == 'A' || getChar == 'E' || getChar == 'I' || getChar == 'O' || getChar == 'U')
                        {
                            totalVowels++;
                        }
                        else if (getChar == 1 || getChar == 2 || getChar == 3 || getChar == 4 || getChar == 5 || getChar == 6 || getChar == 7 || getChar == 8 || getChar == 9)
                        {
                            totalNumbers++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            totalOther++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                alphaPercent = ((countLength - totalNumbers - totalOther) * 100)/countLength;
                vowelPercent = (totalVowels * 100)/countLength;
                numPercent = (totalNumbers * 100)/countLength;
                otherPercent = (totalOther * 100)/countLength;

                cout << "% of alphabets = " << alphaPercent << "%" << endl;
                cout << "% of vowels = " << vowelPercent << "%" << endl;
                cout << "% of numbers = " << numPercent << "%" << endl;
                cout << "% of the rest = " << otherPercent << "%" << endl;
                cout << "Total number of characters = " << countLength << endl;

                inputFile.close();
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Type in an available file." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There is no syntactical error but the output looks like this:

```
Enter the file name:
as.5.txt
% of alphabets = 100%
% of vowels = 0%
% of numbers = 0%
% of the rest = 0%
Total number of characters = 28
```

When it should look like this:

```
Enter the file name:
as.5.txt
% of alphabets = 92%
% of vowels = 32%
% of numbers = 4%
% of the rest = 4%
Total number of characters = 25
```

Comment: Stop using uninitialized variables. You never initialize either of the variables beginning with `count` before incrementing them.

Comment: 1) "_There is no syntactical error_" If the code compiles - it doesn't mean that it runs correctly. Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, to figure out where the code does something, that you didn't expect? 2) The simplest way one may think of is: reading all the file into `std::map<char, int>`, and doing any necessary analysis on it, afterwards.

Comment: Integer division!

Comment: One problem I see right off the bat is that you're comparing a char value to integer literals. if(getChar == 1) will be true not if getChar is '1' but if the underlying integer value of the char is 1 (in ASCII that's the SOH start of header character) try if(getChar == '1' || ... ) instead

Comment: ***else if (getChar == 1 || getChar == 2 || getChar == 3 || getChar == 4 || getChar == 5 || getChar == 6 || getChar == 7 || getChar == 8 || getChar == 9)*** These are wrong.

Comment: Why are you asking for a file name and then only opening the file if it is "as.5.txt"?

Comment: @drescherjm Sure?

Comment: *There is no syntactical error but ...* -- Sorry, programming in C++ doesn't work this way.  If it were this easy, where all you need to do is get a program to compile with no errors, then *no* program would have bugs.

Comment: *When it should look like this:* -- Also, don't take this too harshly, but when you write a program, *expect* logical bugs to appear, where *you* have to sit down and solve them by debugging.  It is not an "error" to write a program and find out it has bugs -- making logical bugs and how to fix them is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.  The thing you should not do is write a program, discover it doesn't produce the correct results, and then without thought post on stack overflow that your program doesn't work properly and for one of us to debug your code.

Comment: @TheDude should be comparing characters '0' .. '9' which are different from 1 .. 9.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks like

```
if (userInput == " ")
{
    // ...
    for (unsigned n = 0; n < userInput.length(); ++n)
    {
        // count the various types
    }
}
```

The counting loop will only be run when all the input lines equal `" "`.
Therefore no vowels, digits, ... will be counted.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way to count the vowels in a given `std::string` (you have `#include <string>` so I assume it is acceptable to use it in your assignment). Basically along the lines of [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) and [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) you can write your own helper function to check the input character against the standard vowels.

```
#include <algorithm>   ///< std::count_if
#include <cctype>      ///< std::tolower, std::isdigit, std::isalpha
#include <set>         ///< std::set

bool isvowel(unsigned char ch)
{
    static std::set<unsigned char> const vowels{ 'a','e','i','o','u' };
    // normalize to lowercase before checking for match
    return vowels.find(std::tolower(ch)) != vowels.end();
}
```

Then you can "count" all of the vowels in a given string by leveraging the STL algorithm [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) with your helper function over given string.

```
std::string text; ///< the string to check for vowels
int vowels = std::count_if(text.begin(), text.end(), [](auto ch){ return isvowel(ch); });
```

Hint #1: You can take the line of code above and simply change the last part of it to `return std::isdigit(ch);` and get the digit count "for free".

Hint #2: You can take the line of code above and simply change the last part of it to `return std::isalpha(ch);` and get the alphabetic character count "for free".